# How do I display customer specific information avoiding using xslt?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xslt

My place of work currently maintains a website for several customers which is written using classic asp.  Each customer requires specific parts of the website to be written specifically to them.

For example, customer A requires an Address to be input, displayed and stored in the following format:

```
Address Line 1
Address Line 2
Address Line 3
Address Line 4
Address Line 5
Postcode
```

whereas customer B requires the Address to be input, displayed and stored as:

```
Street
Town
City
Postcode
```

and so forth...

Therefore, my place of work took the path of storing the data as xml in the database and using xsl (of which I currently know little) to transform the data to html.

So if we require information from the user via a html form, the xml is transformed using xsl.  The user then enters the information and submits the data via the form.  An asp page is then used to validate the data.  This asp page is specific to the xsl page used to display the form.  Therefore, we are now in a postion where for each customer we have many xsl pages and many customer specific asp pages (where much of the code is duplicated).

I have been asked to move the site over to asp.net mvc3 and to remove much of the duplication and was wondering what would be the best way to cater for this customer specific field functionality.  My preference would be to keep the data stored as xml as the database layer is accessed using com components which I would like to reuse without changing.

I have read that I could keep the xsl pages and develop an xslt view engine to display the html.  However, I am not sure how I would validate the data when the user submits the form?

What would be the best way to display customer specific fields if I was to remove the xsl completely?  Or would I have to have customer specific views and view models?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use MVC's built in validation / model functionality I think your best bet would be to use the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) or use [DataContracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) to develop something that serializes to and from your XML (once its retrieved from the COM objects, so you don't need to re-code those), then you can use those classes as Models for MVC and use the standard data annotations for taking advantage of the richer MVC model functionality and skip the XSL step entirely.

To couple this with a custom specific view, what I typically do is override the default view engine to have one that actually will try names that are more specific to the customer/object and then fallback to a general one.

This view engine would allow you to pass a view to pass a view name (ie. `FallbackViewEngine.BuildViewName("General", "Customer Name")` and it would look for "General.Customer Name.cshtml" first and then "General.cshtml" as a fallback.  This way you can actually use customer specific views in your view folder.

```
public class FallbackViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    const string NameSeparator = "==";
    const string FileSeparator = ".";

    public static string BuildViewName(string root, params string[] fallbackList)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(root)) throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
        if (fallbackList == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("fallbackList");

        var sb = new StringBuilder(root);

        foreach (var s in fallbackList)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) continue;

            sb.Append(NameSeparator);
            sb.Append(s);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewName)) throw new ArgumentNullException("viewName");

        var names = viewName.Split(new string[] {NameSeparator}, StringSplitOptions.None);

        var searched = new List<string>();

        //iterate from specific to general
        for (var i = names.Length; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            var result = base.FindView(controllerContext, string.Join(FileSeparator, names, 0, i), masterName, useCache);

            if (result.View != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                searched.AddRange(result.SearchedLocations);
            }
        }

        return new ViewEngineResult(searched);                        
    }
}
```